# Pine Script plot based on higher timeframe

Tags: pine-script

I'd like to expand the current TF series to a higher resolution/timeframe on TradingView Pine Script.

For example...

Let's say I have a variable (let's say `result`) with the following series:

```
...,3,0,0,0,2,0,1,0,0,0,16,5,-2,0,0,0,...
```

Here let's say the above the data is on 1m (minute) TF.

So the problem I have is the data is on 1m TF, so when I try to see the indicator on a HTF e.g. 3m, 15m; I cannot see the data in a desirable way but kind of sampled way. e.g. when:

```
// 1m
...,9:00,9:01,9:02,9:03,4,5,6,7,8,(and so on)...
...,3,0,0,0,2,0,1,0,0,0,16,5,-2,0,0,0,...
```

It would be:

```
// 3m
...,9:00,9:03,9:06,9:09,12,15,(and so on)...
...,3,0,1,0,-2,...
```

See? While in the above case a value such as "16" is a significant value in 1m, in 3m it's wiped out.

As a solution to this I want to see a highest(max)/lowest(min) value on the HTF.

So what I need here is something similar to:

```
// 3m
...,9:00,9:03,9:06,9:09,12,15,(and so on)...
...,3,2,1,16,-2,...
```

So which can be converted to:

```
// 1m
...,9:00,9:01,9:02,9:03,4,5,6,7,8,(and so on)...
...,3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,1,16,16,16,-2,-2,-2,...
```

Sorry for the poor explanation but basically what I'd like to achieve is to plot the above data series on 1m TF.

Btw `security()` doesn't work in this case. That's the problem. `security()` doesn't replicate the series value, but it recalculates the series.

```
// this does an another thing
plot(security(syminfo.tickerid, "3", result))
```

So, what can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//@version=5
indicator("min/max over higher tf", overlay = true)

higher_tf = input.timeframe("3")

tf_denom = timeframe.in_seconds(higher_tf) / timeframe.in_seconds(timeframe.period)

if int(tf_denom) != tf_denom
    runtime.error("Higher timeframe must be divisible by Chart timeframe")

new_higher_tf = timeframe.change(higher_tf)

var float min = na
var float max = na

if new_higher_tf
    min := low
    max := high
else
    min := math.min(min, low)
    max := math.max(max, high)

plot(min, color = color.red)
plot(max, color = color.green)
```